# Disable auto refresh when switching to Responsive Design Mode in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

To adjust my site CSS, I often go in developer mode and adjust CSS directly there to have a live preview. but then, I want to switch responsive design mode on or off to see if other display is not broken by what I just edited. Unfortunately, it reloads the page and discard all modifications I had just done.

How to avoid auto reload of the page in Firefox when toggling Responsive Design Mode on or off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options *Reload when touch simulation is toggled* and *Reload when user agent is changed* that cause the page to reload automatically when enabled.

If you disable those two options the page should not get reloaded when switching to Responsive Design Mode.

[image: Toggle options for page reload in Responsive Design Mode]